# Webservice method doesnt accept xml as parameter

Tags: java, web-services

I am facing an issue in web service. I have a web service method in my webservice. If I send certificate as string my code is accepting the certificate and logic is getting executed. But I send any xml file then my service method is not accepting the xml content. May I know the reason as xml file is also a string, I am confused why its not accepting the xml content.

May I know how to read xml content in this method. I don't require any code parsing of this xml. I want only to receive that xml certificate content.

Could any one suggest on this?

Below is the method which is created in webservice class

```
uploadData(String  certificate).
```

Comment: Please include 1) the Java code, 2) the sample XML input.

Answer (score 0):

if you using SOAP based web service then i think you may not used it.
but in case of RESTful service you will not faced such errors, as RESTful is designed for same

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am using AXIS2 webservices will this be possible for these webservices.